# spring loading context files with maven project

Tags: spring, maven

I use maven build in my application. I have package like:

```
1> src/test/java   // for Test application
2> src/main/java   // code 
3> src/main/resource  // resource files
```

at 1> i have written a Test file as:

```
public void testLoginDetails() {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml" });
```

Home-ctx is available at 2> ie src/main/java/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml

but when i run the application I am getting following common error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
```

I know this is classpath problem for xml file loading. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move

`src/main/java/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml`

to

`src/main/resources/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml`

Classpath resources need to go in a `resources` folder - currently you've got them under a `java` folder, which is for sources, not resources.

If the resource is used only for testing, it should live in `src/test/resources`. For production resources, they go under `src/main/resources`.

References

- [Maven - introduction to the standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)